# Sort alphabetically by custom field

Tags: custom-field, array, sort, meta-value

I'm trying to change the sort order of a custom field in a custom post type.

I want it to be be alphabetical by the 'location' name.

It's sorting by location, but not keeping them in alphabetical order.

[image: screenshot]

Here is my code:

```
<?php foreach ( $tags as $tag) : $term = get_term_by("slug", $tag, "post_tag", "ARRAY_A");?>


                            <?php   $i =1; 
                                    $args = array(
                                        'tag' => $tag,
                                        'post_type' => 'jobs',
                                        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                                        'order' => 'ASC',
                                        'meta_key' => 'location',
                                        'nopaging' => 'true'
                                    );
                                    $query = new WP_Query( $args ); $length = count($query->posts); 
                                    if ($query -> have_posts()) : ?>
                                    <h4 class="section-title"><?php echo $term["name"] ;?></h4>
                                        <table>
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>
                                                        <h4>&nbsp;Position</h4>
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        <h4>&nbsp;Deadline</h4>
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        <h4>&nbsp;Pay &amp; Hours</h4>
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        <h4>&nbsp;Location</h4>
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th>
                                                        <h4>&nbsp;Apply Online</h4>
                                                    </th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                        <?php while ( $query->have_posts()): ?>

                                            <?php $query -> the_post();?>
                                            <tr align="left" valign="top">
                                                <td style="width:140px"><a href="<?php the_field("job_description") ;?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title() ;?></a></td>
                                                <td style="width:140px"><?php the_field("deadline"); ?></td>
                                                <td style="width:140px"><?php the_field("pay_hours"); ?></td>
                                                <td style="width:140px"><?php the_field("location"); ?></td>
                                                <td style="width:140px"><a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>job-application?field1=<?php the_title() ;?>&field1258=<?php the_field("location")?>&field1280=<?php echo urlencode(get_field("ymca_email_contact"));?>" target="_new">Apply Now</a></td>
                                            </tr>

                            <?php   endwhile; ?>
                                            </tbody>
                            </table>
```

What is my issue?

Kevin

Comment: Have you turned on WP debug mode?  Might show an error.  Your query looks correct for the sort you are attempting.

Comment: Debug doesn't show anything:

http://philly.starklmc.com/about-us/careers/

Comment: Can you post more of that template code?  I wonder if there is something a layer up in your nested loops affecting this.

Comment: @jdm2112 Here is the full template.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/btuc6rplkr6laf2/job-application.php?dl=0

Comment: I read a few other posts on this looking for a clue. Saw a unique problem when sorting by ACF fields but it's not quite your issue. I would recommend you copy to another file and strip it down.  Remove the tag from the query, etc until the meta sort DOES work.  Something will prove to be the issue.  Good luck.